# MongoError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined, while using $or

Tags: node.js, mongodb, waterline

I'm using waterline,and I imported the database with the mongoimport command. I use the native driver to connect to mongo, calling .find and .aggregate.

When using $or to lookup multiple records with results from a previous set of queries. The array looks something like

```
[{"\"ProductID\"": "76543"},{"\"ProductID\"": "74632"}, {"\"ProductID\"": "76534",...n}]
```

Pay no mind to the KEY, that is a temporary set up due to a control character in the file used to convert the csv to json and then mongoimporting the new file.

I should be able to do the following query with the array.

```
collection.find({$or: arrayResults }).toArray().then(function(result)...
```

I then receive the error: **MongoError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

I was able to stop the error by making the array smaller. This wasn't designed to force its user's to query in batches but i'm not sure how to fix the problem.

As a workaround, The aggregation framework $match stage doesn't seem to be having any problems.

```
collection.aggregate([{$match: {$or: arrayResults}}}]).toArray().then(....
```

This problem is I'm not using "id" in my query, so I don't understand whats wrong.

Comment: Try `{"ProductID": "74632"},` without `\"`?

Comment: thats what they key looks like in the db, so right now it has to be that way. do you really think that's going to damage a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this issue came down to is compatability with the node.js driver.

After exploring the many avenues of writing the code to find the problem. As well as experiencing inconsistant errors and just simple hanging in the application.

I verified the version of the node drivers were 2.0.44. My DB version was 3.2 for mongodb. mongoDB clearly states that compatability for the nodejs driver with 3.2 is >= 2.1.0.

i'm surprised noone showed up to suggest this that was an expert with mongoDB considering that the error that was occuring was completely inconsistant with values in my database.